# Is it legal for an investment firm to announce some positions/trades that aren't true?

Tags: united-states, finance, sec, investment

Taking as example the [2021 GameStop short squeeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GameStop_short_squeeze), is it legal for an investment firm to announce some positions/trades that aren't true?

The question was triggered by this [Tweet](https://twitter.com/xtrends/status/1355264538023759880) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210201071707/https://twitter.com/xtrends/status/1355264538023759880)):

[image]

Comment: For what it is worth, it looks like the company made a press release to CNBC a media outlet, rather than putting out an advertisement, contrary to what the Tweet said. And, there is no obvious basis for the assertion that their statement isn't true. There are lots of obvious reasons to disclose that fact as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

Lying about a trade would be [market manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_manipulation).